# How to use two for in loops in JS to get data

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

logic like---> I create a rent system. then one rent can get two cars or more. It also add my database. but I want to show the details in the front end but the table shows only one row only. How can I fix it.

I also create a rent entity and rent details entity.
rent EntitY code,

```
   @Id
private String rentID;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "cusID",referencedColumnName = "cusNicID")
private User cusID;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rID",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<RentDetails> rentDetails = new ArrayList<>();
```

My rentDetails entity,

```
  @Id
private String rentDetailID;

private String rentLosWaiver;
private String pickUpDate;
private String returnDate;
private String rentLosWaiverRecipt;
private String rentTotal;
private String rentStatus;


@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "rID",referencedColumnName = "rentID")
private Rent rID;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cID",referencedColumnName = "carID")
private Vehicle cID;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "dIC",referencedColumnName = "driver_NIC")
 private Driver dIC;
```

Then I use to get data in to the front end using AJAX request,

```
  $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: "http://localhost:8080/EasyCarBackEnd_war_exploded/rent",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async:true,
        success: function (res) {
            console.log("all Data "+ res)
            console.log("Print Pendinr Request" + res.data[0].rentID)

            console.log("Print Pendinr Request CAr ID" + res.data[0].rentDetails[0].cID.carID)

            for (var i in res.data) {
            // for (var x in res.data) {
                let rentID = res.data[i].rentID;
                let cusID = res.data[i].cusID.cusNicID;
                let cusName = res.data[i].cusID.name;


                    let carID = res.data[i].rentDetails[1].cID.carID;
                    let carName = res.data[i].rentDetails[1].rentDetailID;

                    let dID = res.data[i].driver_NIC;
                    let dStatus = "Avliable";
                    let pickDate = res.data[i].pickUpDate;
                    let dropDate = res.data[i].returnDate;
                    let reqStatus = res.data[i].rentStatus;


                    var row = `<tr><td>${rentID}</td><td>${carID}</td><td>${carName}</td><td>${cusID}</td><td> ${cusName}</td>
<td> ${dID}</td><td> ${dStatus}</td><td> ${pickDate}</td><td> ${dropDate}</td><td> ${reqStatus}</td><td><button  class="btn btn-warning fff" id="${carID}" onclick="updateDetailsCar(this)">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger " id="${carID}" onclick="DeleteCar(this)">Delete</button></td></tr>`;
                    $('#tblAllRequest').append(row);
                }
            }
        // }
    })
```

But only one row shows the table.
How can I print two rows on my table?

Comment: Please show the structure of the `console.log("all Data "+ res);` output.

Comment: out put should be  all Data [object Object]

Comment: console.log("Print Pendinr Request" + res.data[0].rentID) out put ->  Print Pendinr RequestF001

Comment: console.log("Print Pendinr Request CAr ID" + res.data[0].rentDetails[0].cID.carID) out put -->Print Pendinr Request CAr IDV001

Comment: @WillWalsh can you help me to for this